# How to lock the screen to remain vertical/portrait?

Tags: auto-rotation, orientation

When screen rotate lock is off, the screen on my tablet has four possible orientations: A, B, C, and D, as illustrated below:

[image: screen rotation]

I know that it is possible to lock the screen to one orientation -- A *or* B *or* C *or* D -- by deselecting the screen rotation icon in the Notifications pulldown:

[image: screen rotate icon]

But **I want to lock the screen** so that it is *always* in *either* the **A** *or* the **C** orientation (**vertical/portrait**), and *never* in the **B** or **D** orientation (horizontal/landscape).  In other words, I want the screen to always be oriented vertically, but still respecting the particular vertical orientation (gravity).

Is this possible?

You might wonder why I want to do this -- I am physically disabled, and it would (really help me out if this were somehow possible.  I'm running Android 7.1.1 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the app called "Ultimate Rotation Control" will do what you are asking. Here's the link:
[Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate&hl=en)

Comment: +1 just for mentioning this particular app.

Answer (score 2):

To lock your screen to have always (**vertical/portrait**) install and use 
**Screen Rotation Control**  available on the Play store 
[here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bong.android.androidlock&hl=en)